# About the usage of classpath in spring context config file

Tags: java, spring, web

in the spring context config, I want to pass some file in the the web project's path: `app/src/main/resources`, I use `"classpath"` tag to pass the file as a constructor parameter into the the bean class:

```
<beans:bean id="beanId" class="com.sample.class">
    <beans constructor-arg value="classpath:test.properties"/>
</beans:bean>
```

In the bean, when it receives this parameter in its constructor, it prints out the value to see if the actual path of the file is passed in. But when I run the codes, it simply prints out `"classpath:test.properties"` directly instead of the actual path, therefore I can't get the correct value to further process, could anyone provide some advice on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the property value in your desired bean, do the following

```
@Value("${appConf.testValue}")
String testValue;
```

Not necessary to pass the property file to bean, But in order to do this your Spring context should be load the property file for that you will have to use the

```
<bean id="viewPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
    </property>
 </bean>
```